# How can I clear the terminal screen in Go?

Tags: go

Are there any standard method in Golang to clear the terminal screen when I run a GO script? or I have to use some other libraries?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Note:** Running a command to clear the screen is not a secure way. Check the other answers here as well.

---

You have to define a clear method for every different OS, like this. When the user's os is unsupported it panics

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

var clear map[string]func() //create a map for storing clear funcs

func init() {
    clear = make(map[string]func()) //Initialize it
    clear["linux"] = func() { 
        cmd := exec.Command("clear") //Linux example, its tested
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Run()
    }
    clear["windows"] = func() {
        cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "cls") //Windows example, its tested 
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Run()
    }
}

func CallClear() {
    value, ok := clear[runtime.GOOS] //runtime.GOOS -> linux, windows, darwin etc.
    if ok { //if we defined a clear func for that platform:
        value()  //we execute it
    } else { //unsupported platform
        panic("Your platform is unsupported! I can't clear terminal screen :(")
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("I will clean the screen in 2 seconds!")
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    CallClear()
    fmt.Println("I'm alone...")
}
```

(the command execution is from @merosss' answer)

Comment: This works on Windows: `cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "cls")`

Comment: I can confirm that. This syntax was the **only** one working for me (win10 x64). Upvoted the answer and comment. Thanks!

Comment: It's overkill to run a command just to clear the screen, and it's not secure.

Comment: @InancGumus Could you explain, or point me in the direction of an explanation as to why this method is not secure?

Comment: Please check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53673326/115363

Answer (score 72):

You could do it with [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```
fmt.Print("\033[H\033[2J")
```

But you should know that there is no bulletproof cross-platform solution for such task. You should check platform (Windows / UNIX) and use `cls` / `clear` or escape codes.

Answer (score 20):

Don't use command execution for this. It's overkill, and not guaranteed to work, and it's not secure.

---

I created a small cross-platform package. So it works on Windows, Linux, OS X, etc.

Install it like this:

```
go get github.com/inancgumus/screen
```

Then you can use it like so:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "github.com/inancgumus/screen"
)

func main() {
    // Clears the screen
    screen.Clear()

    for {
        // Moves the cursor to the top left corner of the screen
        screen.MoveTopLeft()

        fmt.Println(time.Now())
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Use [goterm](https://github.com/buger/goterm)

```
package main

import (
    tm "github.com/buger/goterm"
    "time"
)
func main() {
    tm.Clear() // Clear current screen
    for {
        // By moving cursor to top-left position we ensure that console output
        // will be overwritten each time, instead of adding new.
        tm.MoveCursor(1, 1)
        tm.Println("Current Time:", time.Now().Format(time.RFC1123))
        tm.Flush() // Call it every time at the end of rendering
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the source of goterm, it uses the same solution as [Kavu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22892171/474189).

Comment: goterm is overkill for this task (it's a full-fledged, heavy-loaded package). I suggest you to check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53673326/115363

Answer (score 11):

As reported [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Clear_the_screen#Go) you can use the following three lines to clear the screen:

```
c := exec.Command("clear")
c.Stdout = os.Stdout
c.Run()
```

Don't forget to import "os" and "os/exec".

Answer (score 4):

**Easy solution only for nix systems (*linux, unix, etc.*):**

```
fmt.Println("\033[2J")
```

Comment: this is printing at the end of the screen everytime.

Comment: @InancGumus  it explicitely says in the answer "for nix systems" as in unix, linux, mac

Answer (score 2):

Here's a concise way of doing it:

```
package util

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
)

func runCmd(name string, arg ...string) {
    cmd := exec.Command(name, arg...)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Run()
}

func ClearTerminal() {
    switch runtime.GOOS {
    case "darwin":
        runCmd("clear")
    case "linux":
        runCmd("clear")
    case "windows":
        runCmd("cmd", "/c", "cls")
    default:
        runCmd("clear")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me (tested on my mobile phone in termux) this works:

```
os.Stdout.Write([]byte{0x1B, 0x5B, 0x33, 0x3B, 0x4A, 0x1B, 0x5B, 0x48, 0x1B, 0x5B, 0x32, 0x4A})
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest code for Windows and Linux is:

```
package main

import (
 "github.com/MasterDimmy/go-cls"
)
func main() {
 cls.CLS()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).