# Golang fmt.Print("\033c") and fmt.Print("\x1bc") are not clearing screen(ANSI Escape code not working) how to fix?

Tags: windows, go, cmd, ascii, command-prompt

Whenever I run `fmt.Print("\033c")` in Go on Windows cmd it does not clear screen but prints `c` whenever I do `console.log("\033c")` in javascript it works fine.

According to the following links this should have worked:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Windows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#samples

I have tried logging it in javascript and it works fine I also tried adding a \n character to the end which printed `c` and changing it to \x1bc which also just printed: `c`

the following all prints: `c` on windows cmd

```
func main() {
  fmt.Print("\033c")
  fmt.Print("\033c\n")
  fmt.Print("\x1bc")
  fmt.Print("\x1bc\n")
  fmt.Println("\033c")
  fmt.Println("\x1bc")
}
```

I expected that it would just clear the screen as in javascript but for some reason it doesn't

To clarify I am talking about that the [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) is not working.

Comment: fmt.Print("\033c") properly clears the screen on a "normal" terminal. Probably this is a Windows only problem.

Comment: There's a project on github, which seems to send `"\033[2J"` to the output to clear the screen. It's not explicitly mentioned, but might be worth a shot (see if it supports windows): [goterm](https://github.com/buger/goterm). There's a duplicate question about this, BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891644/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-screen-in-go

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clear the terminal screen in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891644/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-screen-in-go)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thank you for your response, I have edited my question, I hope this clarifys that the ANSI escape code not working was the problem, I also answered my own question with the fix I found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that windows needs the ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING(0x0004) console flag I fixed it by using the following code to add the flag to the console:

```
package main

// #include "Windows.h"
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    // Needed for getting handle and getting current console mode
    var mode C.DWORD
    handle := C.GetStdHandle(C.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    C.GetConsoleMode(handle, &mode)

    // Enable Virtual Terminal Processing by adding the flag to the current mode
    C.SetConsoleMode(handle, mode|0x0004)
    fmt.Print("\033c")
}
```

[SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode)

===EDIT===

Like Matmarbon mentioned in the comments `// #include "Windows.h"` line is nessecary and you need to have an `gcc` installed

Comment: You have no idea how long it took me, to find this solution! Thank you! It is also worth mentioning for the beginners (like me) that the `// #include "Windows.h"` line is actually _necessary_ even though it looks like a comment. Also `gcc` should be installed - which I just did via MinGW and change of the `%PATH%` variable.

Comment: @Matmarbon glad I could help and thank you for the tip I added it to the answer